# remove add to cart button from home page Luma

Tags: addtocart

how can i remove or hide the "Add to Cart" button on my home page and category pages? I am using Magento 2.1 Luma as my main template

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>.catalog-category-view .action.tocart, .action.primary, 
.action.tocompare, a.action.tocompare, .action.tocompare, 
.product-item-actions .actions-primary+.actions-secondary 
{display:none;}</style>
```

Ad that to the top of "Content" on any category where you want to hide the add to cart and the compare buttons.